# Referencing individual child widgets in a pyqt5 listWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-signals

I have a bunch of widgets that I want to add into a `QListWidget`. So far the code seems to be working, if not for the issue that it does not look like the widgets can be referenced either by itself or from other widgets due to how I constructed it with a clumsy for loop:

```
for i in self.csv:
                self.constructListItem(i,
                                       type,
                                       {
                                       'Option1':[False],
                                       'Option2':[True,'desc1'],
                                       'Option3':[True,'desc2'],
                                       'Option4':[False],
                                        })
```

where `self.constructListItem` looks like this:

```
def constructListItem(self, columnName, defaultOption, listOptions):
        listFeatureWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        featureWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #widget details
        featureWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent')
        featureWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 210, 901, 91))
        featureWidget.setObjectName("featureWidget")
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(featureWidget)
        verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        feature = QtWidgets.QWidget(featureWidget)
        feature.setObjectName("feature")
        horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(feature)
        horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        featureLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(feature)
        featureLabel.setObjectName("featureLabel")
        featureLabel.setText(columnName)
        horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(featureLabel)
        comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(feature)
        comboBox.setStyleSheet('background-color:white')
        comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(updateSelf)
        #add items from dict into comboBox
        for i in listOptions.keys():
            comboBox.addItem(i)
        comboBox.setCurrentIndex(defaultOption)
        horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(comboBox)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(feature)
        parameterWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(featureWidget)
        parameterWidget.setObjectName("parameterWidget")
        horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(parameterWidget)
        horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        parameterLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(parameterWidget)
        parameterLabel.setObjectName("parameterLabel")
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(parameterLabel)
        spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parameterWidget)
        spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.UpDownArrows)
        spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(spinBox)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(653, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(parameterWidget)
        listFeatureWidget.setSizeHint(featureWidget.sizeHint())
        self.featureList.addItem(listFeatureWidget)
        self.featureList.setItemWidget(listFeatureWidget,featureWidget)
```

The desired behaviour is that everytime a widget's comboBox value changes, it will check against the dictionary passed and based on what the value is collaspe/expand parameterWidget and set the text of one of it's labels. So how do I write this `updateSelf` function so that it can reference the correct widget?

Edit:
A bit of researching later I realised that it needs to be class so I came up with this:

```
class featureItemInstance:
        def __init__(self, master, columnName, defaultOption, listOptions) -> None:
            self.listOptions = listOptions
            self.listFeatureWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.featureWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.featureWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent')
            self.featureWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 210, 901, 91))
            self.featureWidget.setObjectName("featureWidget")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.featureWidget)
            self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.feature = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.featureWidget)
            self.feature.setObjectName("feature")
            self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.feature)
            self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
            self.featureLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.feature)
            self.featureLabel.setObjectName("featureLabel")
            self.featureLabel.setText(columnName)
            self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.featureLabel)
            self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.feature)
            self.comboBox.setStyleSheet('background-color:white')
            self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
            self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.updateSelf)
            for i in listOptions.keys():
                self.comboBox.addItem(i)
            self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(defaultOption)
            self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.comboBox)
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.feature)
            self.parameterWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.featureWidget)
            self.parameterWidget.setObjectName("parameterWidget")
            self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.parameterWidget)
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
            self.parameterLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.parameterWidget)
            self.parameterLabel.setObjectName("parameterLabel")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.parameterLabel)
            self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.parameterWidget)
            self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.UpDownArrows)
            self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
            self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
            self.spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(653, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
            self.horizontalLayout.addItem(self.spacerItem)
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.parameterWidget)
            self.listFeatureWidget.setSizeHint(self.featureWidget.sizeHint())
            master.featureList.addItem(self.listFeatureWidget)
            master.featureList.setItemWidget(self.listFeatureWidget,self.featureWidget)
            self.updateSelf()
        
        def updateSelf(self):
            expand = self.listOptions[self.comboBox.currentText()]
            if expand[0]:
                self.parameterWidget.show()
                self.parameterLabel.setText(expand[1])
            else:
                self.parameterWidget.hide()
```

but for some reason in `updateSelf()` it says that `'featureItemInstance' object has no attribute 'parameterWidget'` despite being declared within the `__init__`, no idea what's wrong.

Comment: 1. as already said for your previous post, you shall ***NOT*** edit a pyuic file (nor try to literally mimic its behavior); it's a bad practice that only results in lots of issues; 2. create a QWidget subclass for the widget so that it can work on its own; 3. the excessive indentation of your first code block is terribly pointless, as it doesn't make your code more readable (which is the main reason for indentation).

Comment: @musicamante sorry the trouble, but how do you subclass a QWidget? I don't really have too much expertise in this area, and the examples I found about that seems to be something to do with cpp, and I managed to get the cpp code of that widget, but I don't really see how to implement it into my program. Do I try to import the class Ui_Form, then use it like how I would use a QWidget?

Comment: Did you read the link in the comment to your last post? Did you *experiment* with that? Besides, subclassing is quite a fundamental aspect in Python (and OOP in general), if you don't know how to do it, I strongly urge you to do some research on the matter.